# Having trouble right-aligning pyramid for Mario problem set

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently doing the Mario problem (less comfortable) for Week 1 of CS50. So far, I can print the hashes of the pyramid, but I am having trouble right-justifying it with the spaces. Would someone be able to pinpoint where I am going wrong? Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int hashes;
int space;
int height;

do 
{
    height = get_int("height: ");
}
while (height < 0 || height > 5);
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
    {
        for (space = (height - 1); space <= 0; space++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (hashes = 1; hashes <= i; hashes++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: `height - 1` is almost never **less than or equal to 0**. Also your other loop is wrong, for height iterations one does `0` to **`<`** `height`. And finally, there are countless duplicates in Stack Overflow **and** https://cs50.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

As Antti said, in your 'spaces' loop, `height - 1` on the first iteration of i (so where i = 0), will never be < or = to 0 (unless height is set to 1).

How many spaces should you print before the # on the first line if your height is set to 5? Is it 4?

So if on the first line int Space = 0, height = 5, what loop code would achieve a result of 4? But consider on the next iteration of Space if int Space = 1, Height = 5 what loop code could achieve a result of 3?

```
 for (space = 0; "this needs to to = 4" ; space++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
```

```
 for (space = 1; "this needs to to = 3" ; space++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
```

The value of 'spaces' changes on every iteration, could you use this?